# SOQL to get attachment(s) on PollPost

Tags: soql, soap-api, sobject

Just curious what SOQL I would use to get the Poll Items 
(attachments) on a FeetItem with the Type PollPost?

So if we had a poll saying, "Whats your favourite color?"

How would I get the line item options, blue, green red etcetra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the new Chatter in Apex feature (formerly "Connect in Apex") that is available in dev preview in Spring 13 and is expected to GA in Summer 13 you can:

- **post feed polls**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedItem(community id, feed type, subject id, FeedItemInput including poll info, null)
- **get information about polls (choices and results, not individual votes)**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedPoll(community id, feed item id) / ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedItem(community id, feed item id)
- **vote on polls**: ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.voteOnFeedPoll(community id, feed item id, choice id)

Spring 13 dev preview doc is in here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can't get feed poll choices via SOQL, inexplicably. You can access them via the FeedPollChoice list, which is available in the Chatter Connect for Apex developer preview (DE only, unless you contact Salesforce to get them to enable in another org).

Comment: Right now I'm querying `HashtagDefinition` then running a SOSL search to find where they're located

Answer (score 0):

You can now read data through soql, write/update permissions are still not present.

Select f.Position, f.IsDeleted, f.Id, f.FeedItemId, f.CreatedDate, f.CreatedById, f.ChoiceBody From FeedPollChoice f